# how to link a library using gcc in windows 10?

Tags: c, curl, gcc

How do you link a library with a file while compiling a c program on Windows 10 using gcc compiler

while reading other stack overflow questions I came across [this](https://curl.se/download.html) download link for the curl library which has  `curl.h` header file

when I try to compile the file I get this error

```
C:\Users\0000\Desktop>gcc simple.c -lcurl
simple.c:2:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <curl/curl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried this line

```
gcc simple.c
```

also tried this but I keep getting this error

```
cl simple.c
```

This is clearly a library linking problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This is clearly a library linking problem" -- no it is not.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147295/about-c-compilation-process-and-the-linking-of-libraries/25150186#25150186 which briefly goes through the parts of a compilation process.  Look at where header files are used. (step 1), look at where the linker is invoked (step 4).  The error is that the compiler can not find a header file and stops.  Take a look at the "-I" flag to gcc or the "/I" flag to cl to see how to fix this.

Comment: _" but I keep getting this error"_ : what error - that is not an error, it look like an attempt to use a different compiler.

Comment: Have you actually got the library?  If you are using MinGW/gcc : https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-curl (it has a huge number of dependencies - it is not trivial).

Answer (score 1):

Test use '-L' gcc flag. This recive the directory where is the lib's files.

Example: gcc simple.c -L curlDownloadDirectory -lcurl

Answer (score 0):

You need libcurl.a (the part you link), and curl.h (the header you include), but you also have to tell the compiler/linker where to look for the header file (`-I <path>`) and where to look for the library (-L ).  You can have multiple `-I` and `-L` specifications.